# Transform env variables during build time with typescript

Tags: typescript

Trying to find a clean way to statically transform `process.env` environment variables using `tsc`. Basically I'm trying to achieve what [babel-plugin-transform-inline-environment-variables](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-inline-environment-variables) does using the typescript complier.

Most issues on the web involve getting the compiler to behave with `process.env` and other solutions recommend tools like `dotenv` to store env vars for later use.

This is particularly useful when environment variables do not contain sensitive information. Example:

```
export const VERSION = process.env.VERSION;
```

Build:

```sh
VERSION='1.2.3' npx tsc --project tsconfig.json
```

Desired output:

```js
export const VERSION = '1.2.3';
```

Comment: I believe that it's not under `tsc` concern because how ts should know to replace the `process.env.VERSION` but not keep it (when you use `dotenv` for example). I would create another process (using plain node) that does this (replacing all the `process.env.*` with the env variables..

Comment: That's fair, I suppose this might be more appropriate for the ts github repo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the passersby I was able to solve this a few different ways:

1. Using babel you can use [`babel-plugin-transform-inline-environment-variables`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-inline-environment-variables)
2. Using `tsc` alone you'll need to pre/post-process transpiled code using some external program like `awk`, `sed`, or some other script
3. Using `pika` I wrote [`pika-plugin-inline-env`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pika-plugin-inline-env) for that
4. Webpack has a plugin for that: https://webpack.js.org/plugins/environment-plugin/
5. Rollup has a plugin for that: https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-inject-process-env

Answer (score 0):

I wrote https://www.npmjs.com/package/netlify-plugin-inline-functions-env-typescript to fix that, check the `inlineAll` param, it might be what you need.