# I need help adding environment variables to my TypeScript toolchain

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, rollup

I am requesting help setting up the compilation and dev environment for a typescript library. The library should work when consumed by a web app framework and when consumed by a script tag. I am currently using Webpack as a dev server so I can debug and TSC to build (cjs + esm). The issue that prompted this post was having to constantly switch my API strings between `http://localhost:8080` to `https://production.com`. **What tools or changes do I need in order to build `dev` and `prod` variables into my compilation?**

Here is what I'm doing so far:

*package.json fragment*

```
"main": "./lib/cjs/index.js",
"module": "./lib/esm/index.js",
"files": [
    "lib/**/*",
    "README.md"
],
"scripts": {
    "build:esm": "tsc -p tsconfig.json --outDir lib/esm --module ES2020 --sourceMap false",
    "build:cjs": "tsc -p tsconfig.json --outdir lib/cjs --module commonjs --sourceMap false",
    "clean:build": "rimraf lib",
    "clean:serve": "rimraf dist",
    "build": "rimraf lib && npm run build:esm && npm run build:cjs",
    "serve": "rimraf dist && webpack-dev-server"
}
```

*webpack.config.js*

```js
const path = require('path')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin')

const SRC = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')
const ENTRTY = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'debug.ts')
const DIST = path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    context: SRC,
    entry: ENTRTY,
    output: {
        path: DIST,
        filename: 'index.js',
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    devServer: {
        contentBase: DIST,
        writeToDisk: true,
        host: '0.0.0.0',
        port: 8080,
        https: true,
    },
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin()
    ],
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js']
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                loader: 'ts-loader',
                include: [SRC]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

My toolchain does not currently allow me to do do this:

```js
import Axios from 'axios'
import SocketIO from 'socket.io-client'

export const axios = Axios.create({
    baseURL: process.env.SERVER_HTTP_URL, //<-- can't do env-vars with tsc build
    withCredentials: true
})
```

Comment: Is the code you're trying to inject the env vars into just the code that's compiled with `tsc`, or Webpack-built code as well?

Comment: It doesn't look like there's an existing option for doing this with plain `tsc` as of [this past summer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65501457/5774952). I have a project where I'm doing the same thing with `sed`. A module like [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/replace-in-file) might also work.

Comment: You could replace an existing file with vars before building.

Comment: @ZacAnger When I'm debugging I use Webpack to hot reload and transpile my code but that's, perhaps unnecessarily, separate from my build step which uses the typescript compiler (tsc). To answer your question - yes, this is one case which I wanted to build with a different string. Right now I physically swap between localhost and production URLs before building.

Comment: @DavidBell Got it, I was asking because DefinePlugin makes that easy in Webpack. But that doesn't help you much. Right now it looks like doing it in another step (with Bash, sed, python, or a separate Node script or whatever) is the only way.

Comment: @ZacAnger I'm happy to use Webpack to build as well but I'm really inexperienced and my first attempt was really complicated and broken. All I wanted to do was have a bundle that could be loaded into a Vue/React/etc projects and another bundle that could be used in a script tag. Wasn't clear at all how to do this

Comment: I'm seeing advice online that Webpack is for apps and Rollup is for libraries. I thought about switching but debugging with webpack-dev-server has been really nice. I wouldn't want to give that piece up but I would be happy to switch to anything else that enabled me to work like I do now. Has anyone ever used Webpack for debugging but rollup for publishing?

Comment: Those are their strengths, but you can use Webpack for libraries and Rollup for apps as well. Webpack Dev Server might not be worth giving up though. I think having a second step with another script to replace those variables in the build output is going to be the least hassle for you.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll give that a go. In regards to this post - I've upvoted your comment, is there another SO appropriate thing I should do. Forgive my ignorance...

Answer (score 0):

typescript cant not do that, but gulp can do it

```
const replace = require('gulp-replace');
const { src, dest } = require('gulp');
 
exports.default = function() {
    return src(['*.js'], {base: './'})
    .pipe(replace('__XXXX__', 'some variables'))
    .pipe(dest('./'));
}
```