# Build-time variables in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Go provides functionality for using build-time variables, so that values in the code can be specified during compilation and linking ([info](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/using-ldflags-to-set-version-information-for-go-applications)). This can be useful for e.g. adding git commit versions, platform information etc to the compiled binary.

Is something similar possible with TypeScript? There appears to be a Webpack plugin that makes something similar possible, but are there any ways to do this with `tsc`?

Comment: It is a [non-goal](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/TypeScript-Design-Goals#non-goals) of the typescript project to build a fully fledged build system. So no it's not possible with ts. You can use a bundler like you discovered to do this. Rollup would probably be more fitting for non-web projects.

Comment: @MaximilianMairinger: That's a nice reference. Thanks. Noted that a goal is to `make the system extensible so that external tools can use the compiler for more complex build workflows`. Wondering if someone managed to hook into this somehow.

Comment: I found `tsup` which I believe does exactly what you want via ["Compile-time environment variables"](https://tsup.egoist.dev/#compile-time-environment-variables). I think you can change build infrastructure from tsc to tsup without too much trouble.

Comment: Thanks for following up on this, @MaximilianMairinger! I also found [some approaches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65501457/13075) that could be used with a bundler (namely webpack and babel). Unfortunately, I did not find anything that used only `tsc`, which is my current case.

Comment: Yes, there are other ways to achieve this. I assume, by your current use of tsc only, that you are building a library. Id personally refrain from using webpack or babel for this use case. But rollup would be a good fit, if you want to use a bundler. Id still recommend tsup though, as the transition from tsc to tsup would probably be easiest. Your search for a tsc solution will be futile, without any manual post/pre processing. And then again, why dont you use a existing tool that builds on typescript.